# Which of these memory management techniques is better in what situations?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, accessor

Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html) shows three officially sanctioned techniques for writing accessor methods that need to retain or release object references.

In the case of the first two techniques (reproduced below), the Apple documentation says that "[t]he performance of technique 2 is significantly better than technique 1 in situations where the getter is called much more often than the setter."

```
// Technique 1
- (NSString*) title
{
    return [[title retain] autorelease];
}

- (void) setTitle: (NSString*) newTitle
{
    if (title != newTitle)
    {
        [title release];
        title = [newTitle retain]; // Or copy, depending on your needs.
    }
}

// Technique 2
- (NSString*) title
{
    return title;
}

- (void) setTitle: (NSString*) newTitle
{
    [title autorelease];
    title = [newTitle retain]; // Or copy, depending on your needs.
}
```

Is this the only difference between technique 1 and technique 2, or does using one over the other have other subtle consequences of which I might need to be aware? And if technique 2 uses a better performing getter, does it follow that technique 1 uses a better performing setter since `title` gets an explicit (and presumably immediate) release?

Answer (score 1):

The getter from 2 and the setter from 1:

```
- (NSString*) title
{
    return title;
}

- (void) setTitle: (NSString*) newTitle
{
    if (title != newTitle)
    {
        [title release];
        title = [newTitle retain]; // Or copy, depending on your needs.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second getter is fragile (it will crash if somebody access's the object's `title` and then releases the object), so the first is generally preferable even if marginally slower.

The first setter is more efficient and will work even in situations where an autorelease pool doesn't exist, so it's preferable. The reason it's more efficient is not just because of autorelease vs. release — it doesn't do any work at all if you try to set the property to its existing value.

Comment: If the dealloc method properly clears variables through the accessors, then the second technique won't cause a crash because the title will be autoreleased, and the second setter is faster when the new title is different. It does use more memory, though, since the old title is not immediately released.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Using accessors in dealloc is not proper, and is in fact considered a bad practice by Apple and most Cocoa programmers I've heard comment on the matter.

Comment: @chuck accessing the getter from technique 1 and then releasing will cause a crash as well.

Comment: @Remover: Why on earth would that cause a crash?

Comment: @chuck because after the autorelease the retain count should be the same as for technique 2. so a release could potentially cause a crash also, no? but just thinking about it now... there shouldn't be any problem with either if the object is already retained before the get. please correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: @Remover: The retain count should be one higher than for technique 2 because of the retain. Autorelease doesn't immediately release the object and thus doesn't cause its retain count to go down — it just adds it to the autorelease pool. The object won't actually be released until the pool is drained. Thus, even if the containing object is released, the value returned from the technique 1 getter will still be retained until the autorelease pool is drained (normally at the next iteration of the event loop). Thus, no crash.

Comment: @chuck: but eventually the object in the autorelease pool will be sent 1 release message (potentially) too many causing a crash. which is the point.

Comment: @Remover: I don't know where this "1 release message too many" came from. I wasn't talking about overreleasing. I was talking about an object's property being released along with the object even though the property is still being used in the surrounding context. For example: `Foo *foo = [Foo new]; NSString *name = [foo name]; [foo release]; return [name stringByAppendingString:@" is my name"];` — crashes using getter 2, works perfectly with getter 1.

Comment: @chuck: aha! that's where all this horrendous mess has come from... that clears it up then.